# WebRequest cannot get the request stream

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a HttpWebRequest which registers accounts for me.
I'm using a loop for it to register new accounts with only 1 thing changing, the username.
But for some reason it only works twice, the third time it will reach a certain line calling the function "webRequest.GetRequestStream();" and it will never finish that, it will not throw an error or anything.
This is my first HttpWebRequest, and it is very messy.
For people wondering, value is a string with the registration 'values' in there. The first 2 times do actually register the accounts, so it does work.

```
    public static HttpWebRequest Get()
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://87.255.55.218/register") as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.Host = "87.255.55.218";
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Hacker";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        webRequest.Referer = "http://yougothacked.com";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        webRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive, "115");
        return webRequest;
    }

    public static void Register(string username)
    {
        string value = Value.Replace("replace", username);
        WebRequest webRequest = Get();
        webRequest.ContentLength = value.Length;
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        Stream reqStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();

        reqStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value), 0, value.Length);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        reqStream.Flush();
        reqStream.Close();
        reqStream.Dispose();
    }
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: As a side note, if you put your webRequest in a using statement you get the benefits of a Dispose call with try finally "built in", `using (WebRequest webRequest = Get()) { /* code */ }`

Comment: webRequest is not disposable.

Comment: @Patrick I see, thanks! I appreciate the help. :)
Any idea why this code doesn't work though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *strongly* suspect that the problem is in some code you haven't shown - namely that when you *use* the request, you're not disposing of the response properly. (Just like you should put the code using the request stream in a `using` block.)

If you don't dispose of the response, that response will hold onto a connection to the server until a finalizer releases it. Connections to individual servers are pooled.

In short: make sure you put the response in a `using` block like this:

```
using (WebResponse response = req.GetResponse())
{
    ...
}
```

and I suspect you'll find it works however many requests you make.

On the other hand, using `WebClient` as Darin suggested may well make your life simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the `Referer` and `UserAgent` you are sending I have some doubts from ethics standpoint about what you are doing here. This being said you may try to clean your code using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Hacker";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = "http://yougothacked.com";
    client.UploadValues("http://87.255.55.218/register", new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "username", "foo" },
        { "someOtherParam", "value" }
    });
}
```

If this doesn't work then maybe, well, the server throttles multiple registration requests from the same IP. Of course you could always contact the provider and ask him whether this might be the case.

Comment: Don't worry, I won't be doing anything illegal.
I had no idea what to fill in. I am not sure how to use this, I am a complete newbie at this point.

Comment: Well simply write a function containing my code and pass the username as parameter. Then try calling the function with different usernames and see what gives.

Comment: should I set the method to "POST" if so, how?

Comment: @Basser, no you don't need to. `UploadValues` does this automatically. You also don't need to set the Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: right now, I believe it uploads all those values, but it is not actually registering the accounts. Should "{ "submit", "Register"}" be in there?